# Plane Curves as Cylindrical Helices??

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

In Barrett O'Neil's *Elementary Differential Geometry*, the following theorem is provided:

> **Theorem 4.6:** A regular curve $\alpha$ with curvature $\kappa > 0$ is a cylindrical helix iff the ratio $\tau / \kappa$ is a constant.

Here, $\tau $ refers to the torsion of $\alpha$. My question is the following: If the torsion of every plane curve is 0, doesn't any plane curve  with $\kappa > 0$ (e.g. a circle) satisfy the classification of a cylindrical helix by the above theorem?

My intuition tells me "no," and in fact, Barrett later goes on to provide a list saying that a regular curve with positive curvature is a cylindrical helix iff $\tau / \kappa$ is a non-zero constant, but in his proof of Theorem 4.6 (given below), I don't really see where having a non-zero constant ratio would play a role (or where having a ratio identically 0 would pose a problem). Here's the proof he provides:

[image]

Any help/clarification regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It depends on the definition. A plane curve does have the property that its tangent vector makes a constant angle with a fixed vector (namely, the normal to the plane). What is O’Neill’s actual *definition*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of definition. Usually an [helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) is a 3D curve not lying in a plane.

The circle is a degenerate case. But you're right that it satisfies the definition that the tangent has a constant angle with a fixed axis.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the circular cylinder. The geodesics are lines, circles or circular helices. These curves all have the constant curvature. But if you consider the osculating planes (span by T and N) of them, lines and circles have the zero change from the plane which means they have zero torsion. Then, torsion/kappa =0 for these curves which is constant. Since the helix has no zero torsion, you can consider lines and circles as a degenerate form of helices.